# Is it possible to "downgrade" an app from Hobby to Free?

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to change a dyno type from "Hobby" to "Free" on Heroku. Is it possible?

When I click on "Change Dyno Type", a dialog comes and it doesn't have "Free" option.

[image]

Comment: How many process types do you have? How many dynos? From [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types): "If an app uses free dynos, it can use only free dynos for all of its process types... Apps running on free or hobby dynos can have only one dyno running per process type. Additionally, apps running on free dynos are limited to a maximum of two concurrently running dynos."

Comment: @zolbayar did you ever solve this? I can't figure it out either. If I turn it off, it shuts off completely. If I turn it on, it's stuck on the hobby/$7month

Comment: @A.com, nope. I switched to serverless.

Comment: I heard back from support. It's actually related to teams. If you do it on your personal account you can. If the app is under a team you created, $7 (hobby) is the lowest you can go.

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to switch the Dyno tier to free. But the current Dyno is in hobby tier or higher and belongs to a team. Because teams cannot have Dynos in any tier lower than hobby we will need to transfer the app to a specific user. **Warning the following process will cause other people on the team to lose access.**

1. go to the Resources tab and turn off the Dyno.
2. go to the Settings tab and transfer ownership to the designated user that will be taking over the account.
3. log into the account that now has ownership of the app.
4. go to the Resources tab and click the Change Dyno Type button
5. select the free tier and turn on the dyno